# How do I Seperate A Stroke from a logo or shape layer in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, layers, shapes, stroke

Hello I have a logo and I want turn the logo into a stroke only in illustrator. I cant belive I cant remember how to do this so frustrating. I looked on youtube and im not getting a clear answer on how to do this. All i want is outline stroke only of a logo.

The logo is vector and I already added in the white stroke.

Screenshot below I want remove the orange and have the white stroke only.

[image]

Comment: Is this logo a raster image or vector?

Comment: this logo is vector. I dida control y to see the outlines and i added the stroke myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select all (`Select > All`)
- Set the **fill** to `none` in the **Color Panel** (`Window > Color`)
- Set the **stroke** to a color in the **Color Panel**
- Set the stroke weight in the **Stroke Panel** (`Window > Stroke`)

[image]

---

You *can* also do all this via the **Appearance Panel** (`Window > Appearance`).

Merely click the colors or the stroke weight in *that* panel..

[image]

---

You can review some basic Illustrator tutorials which are provided free of charge by Adobe [**HERE**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/tutorials.html).

Comment: I thought the logo is expanded.

Comment: @Vikas Read the comment under the question.. the stroke was added by the user. I *seriously doubt* it's been expanded. Especially since how to remove the fill seems to be the hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

If the whole logo is expanded (*Object > Expand*) and if each shape is *independent* (I mean if the white shapes are already *cropped* and there's no white shapes behind orange shapes), you can just use Direct Selection tool and select them each and delete it.

You can also use *Shape Builder* tool for this (again it works if whole logo is expanded):

Just press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while you click on orange shapes to remove them.

[image]

Note: To expand the logo, select all the artwork, go to *Object > Expand* and press OK.

[image]